# Getting a specific cell value in an Access Database with C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

In my database, I have 3 columns: time, strike and vol. I am unable to get for example the 3rd value of the 2nd column. I am only able to get the 1st value of any column.

What I want is to store for example the 3rd value of the 2nd column in another variable and then proceed with some calculations. In other words, I need to get a couple of values at specific places in specified columns.

Any help is appreciated.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mike\\Documents\\Database1.mdb;";

    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
    MyConn.Open();

    string StrCmd = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    OleDbCommand Cmd =  new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);

    OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

   string VolT0;
   string VolT1;
   string VolK0;
   string VolK1;

   if (ObjReader != null)
   {
       while (ObjReader.Read())
       {
        VolT0 = ObjReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
        VolK0 = ObjReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
        //VolK1 = ObjReader.GetValue(2).ToString(); //here is the problem: here I need to get the 3rd value in this column but it's not working !


        Console.WriteLine(VolT0 + " - " + VolK0 + "\n");
       }
   }

   ObjReader.Close();
   MyConn.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please define what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OleDbDataReader` reads database rows *one-by-one*.

```
while (ObjReader.Read())
{
     VolT0 = ObjReader.GetValue(0).ToString(); //time column value
     VolK0 = ObjReader.GetValue(1).ToString(); //strike column value
     VolK1 = ObjReader.GetValue(2).ToString(); //vol column value

     Console.WriteLine("time = {0}, strike = {1}, vol = {2}", VolT0 , VolK0, VolK1 );
}
```

If you want to ***3rd value of the 2nd column***, you can set a `counter = 0` in your `while` statement, increase at the last, and call the `VolK0` value (2nd column) when the counter is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

try below, if you need 3rd value that means index of that column is 2.  since you are using while loop and assign values to same fields at every row those assigns field values overwrite by the new row values. if you need to get only a specific row value, you can use where clause and filter only that record.

```
   if (ObjReader != null)
   {
       while (ObjReader.Read())
       {
        VolT0 = !ObjReader.IsDBNull(0)?ObjReader.GetValue(0).ToString():string.Empty;
        VolK0 = !ObjReader.IsDBNull(1)?ObjReader.GetValue(1).ToString():string.Empty;
        VolK1 = !ObjReader.IsDBNull(2)?ObjReader.GetValue(2).ToString():string.Empty;
       }
   }
```